# Perl serializing and Deserializing hash of hashes

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to serialize a hash of hashes and then deserializing it to get back the original hash of hashes ..the issue is whenever i deserialize it ..it appends an autogenerated $var1 eg.

original hash

```
%hash=(flintstones => {
    husband   => "fred",
    pal       => "barney",
},
jetsons => {
    husband   => "george",
    wife      => "jane",
    "his boy" => "elroy",  
},
);
```

comes out as
     $VAR1 = {
          'simpsons' => {
                          'kid' => 'bart',
                          'wife' => 'marge',
                          'husband' => 'homer'
                        },
          'flintstones' => {
                             'husband' => 'fred',
                             'pal' => 'barney'
                           },
};

is there any way i can get the original hash of hashes without the $var1..??

Comment: `$VAR1` is not prepended. It's part of the serialisation. What makes you think that gives a different hash after you deserialise it? How do you deserialise it?

Comment: Personally, I would serialise to JSON using JSON::XS. Data::Dumper is a debugging tool, not a good serialiser. Especially not with the default options.

Comment: i have serialized/deserialized using Freeze/thaw...I need to get the original hash so that i can do some calculations on it ...

Comment: The output you provided is the serialisation created by Data::Dumper. `$VAR1` is part of Data::Dumper's serialisation. You've just showed that Storable worked correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've proved that Storable worked perfectly fine. The `$VAR1` is part of Data::Dumper's serialisation.

```
use Storable     qw( freeze thaw );
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my %hash1 = (
   flintstones => {
      husband  => "fred",
      pal      => "barney",
   },
   jetsons => {
      husband  => "george",
      wife     => "jane",
     "his boy" => "elroy",  
   },
);

my %hash2 = %{thaw(freeze(\%hash1))};

print(Dumper(\%hash1));
print(Dumper(\%hash2));
```

As you can see, both the original and the copy are identical:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'jetsons' => {
                         'his boy' => 'elroy',
                         'wife' => 'jane',
                         'husband' => 'george'
                       },
          'flintstones' => {
                             'husband' => 'fred',
                             'pal' => 'barney'
                           }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'jetsons' => {
                         'his boy' => 'elroy',
                         'wife' => 'jane',
                         'husband' => 'george'
                       },
          'flintstones' => {
                             'husband' => 'fred',
                             'pal' => 'barney'
                           }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set `$Data::Dumper::Terse` to `1`, then Data::Dumper will try to skip these variable names (but the result could sometimes be no longer parseable by `eval`).

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

becomes now:

```
{
  'jetsons' => {
                 'his boy' => 'elroy',
                 'wife' => 'jane',
                 'husband' => 'george'
               },
  'flintstones' => {
                     'husband' => 'fred',
                     'pal' => 'barney'
                   }
}
```

Maybe something like [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) or [YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML) would be better for your purpose?